# Serving tens of thousands of directories in nginx, substring of http_host

Tags: nginx

We will be hosting static backup copies of 30k+ domains and would like to setup a directory structure and serve it dynamically via a single `server {}` block. We would like to avoid issues caused by too many folders within a single folder.

Is there a substring function or similar within NGINX that we could use to generate an alias path based the hostname.

Example

```
location / {
   set $letter substr($http_host, 0, 1);
   alias /var/www/$letter/$http_host/;
}
```

So that somedomain.com would resolve to the directory:

```
/var/www/s/somedomain.com/
```

Other suggestions are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

This case is documented in http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html.

You can do it like this:

```
server {
    server_name (?<domain>.+);

    root /var/www/$domain;
}
```

So, here we use a regular expression capture to get the domain name into `$domain` variable, and then use the variable as the `root`.

You can use a more refined regular expression if there is some pattern in domain names.

Comment: `server_name (?<domain>(?<letter>.).*); root /var/www/$letter/$domain;` will extract first letter as PA wants